# Почему JavaScript обрезает миллисекунды при получении даты от сервера?

Tags: javascript, rest, .net-core

Есть такая ситуация: с сервера приходит Json, в котором есть поле с датой `2021-04-09T19:39:45.26918Z`.
Я использую его для отображения пользователю и храню его в типе `Date`.
Бывают случаи, когда мне надо полученную дату без преобразования вернуть на сервер в виде параметра запроса. Я использую конвертацию `date.toJSON()`, однако на сервер приходят не полные данные, так как JavaScript почему-то обрезает миллисекунды.

```
new Date('2021-04-09T19:39:45.26918Z').toJSON() // Получаю 2021-04-09T19:39:45.269Z
```

Куда подевалось значение 18? `26918Z -> 269Z` Таким образом для сервера это уже разные даты.
Как избежать такой потери данных?

Стек: JavaScript, .net core 3.1

Comment: По стандарту точность Date ограничена миллисекундой

Comment: @andreymal, а есть ли какой либо другой тип данных для dateTime без это ограничения?

Comment: Просто оставляйте строку как есть без преобразования в Date, например?

Comment: @andreymal, хорошо, я буду иметь этот вариант ввиду. А пока подожду ещё вариантов ответа, вдруг будет чудо)

Comment: чуда не случится - toJSON преобразуем в ISO со строго ограниченным числом символов

Comment: Возможно, чудом является [Temporal](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/index.html), но это не точно

Comment: new Date('2021-04-09T19:39:45.26918Z').getMilliseconds() вернет всего лишь три знака. Вероятно, объект Date просто не хранит больше. Так что, делайте сами json

Comment: милисекунды это и есть тысячные секунды .001 три знака за запятой, в крайнем случае можно парсить такие строки регуляркой

Answer (score 0):

Вот вариант извлечения регуляркой

```js
date = '2021-04-09T19:39:45.26918Z'
// все цифры после точки
console.log(date.match(/(\d{5})Z$/)[1])

// только недостающие
console.log(date.match(/(\d{2})Z$/)[1])
```